# Create a new HTML page and add content using PHP

Tags: php, html, admin, panel

I am trying to create new page (file) using PHP.

I have opened and created the page and I have add it content from MySQL but I couldn't get id variable from the previous page.

My admin panel is like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sayfaekle'])) {
        $baslik = $_POST['baslik'];
        $text = $_POST['editor1'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sayfa (sayfa_baslik , sayfa_text) VALUES ('$baslik' , '$text')";

        $db->exec($sql);
        $id=$db->lastInsertId();

        echo "basarılı";
        include "sayfagonder.php";
    }                                   
?>
```

In here, I get baslik and yazi and insert into database successfully. I also get id successfully.

In other page that creates a new PHP page codes are like this:

```
<?php
    $_GET['id'] = $id;
    ini_set('display_errors','0');
    error_reporting(0);

    $pagename = '../'.$baslik. '.php' ;

    $myfile = fopen( $pagename   , "w");
    $text = ' <?php 

    include "config.php";

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    echo $id;
    $sayfasor=$db->prepare("select * from sayfa where sayfa_id=$id");
    $sayfasor->execute(array(0));
    $sayfacek=$sayfasor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    include "header.php";
?>

<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pageana">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h1><?php  echo $sayfacek["sayfa_baslik"];  ?></h1>
                <?php  echo $sayfacek["sayfa_text"]; ?>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
    include "footer.php";
?> ';

    fwrite($myfile , $text);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

And I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\doktor\deneme56.php on line 5
```

I can't get the value of id..

Comment: I assume you're creating a page on the fly. But when you access the page you created, you'll need to have `url/?id=something`. That will make you have a value inside `$_GET['id']`. Just because you've set `$_GET['id'] = something` in the current page, doesn't mean that it will be there in the next (or even in the generated page)

Comment: what's with the `$text = ' <?php etc etc `??? that will not work

Comment: btw; too many questions and none accepted.

Comment: And that HTML after `?>` wouldn't be part of the generated file, since it won't be in the variable.

Comment: Not ruling out a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the value of `$id` but that value is not persisting. Set the value in a `php $_SESSION` variable then access it on new page. Something like this -

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['sayfaekle'])) {
        $baslik = $_POST['baslik'];
        $text = $_POST['editor1'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sayfa (sayfa_baslik , sayfa_text) VALUES ('$baslik' , '$text')";

        $db->exec($sql);
        $id=$db->lastInsertId();

        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        echo "basarılı";
        include "sayfagonder.php";
    }
?>
```

Now you can access this value on new page like this -

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_GET['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
    ini_set('display_errors','0');
    error_reporting(0);

    $pagename = '../'.$baslik. '.php' ;

    $myfile = fopen( $pagename   , "w");
    $text = ' <?php 

    include "config.php";

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    echo $id;
    $sayfasor=$db->prepare("select * from sayfa where sayfa_id=$id");
    $sayfasor->execute(array(0));
    $sayfacek=$sayfasor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    include "header.php";
    ?>
    <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="pageana">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h1><?php  echo $sayfacek["sayfa_baslik"];  ?></h1>
    <?php  echo $sayfacek["sayfa_text"]; ?>
            </div>

            </div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php
    include "footer.php";
?> ';

fwrite($myfile , $text);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

> Now coming to your code. When you already have value in Session variable you don't need to assign in $_GET variable. Access it directly.

Comment: Missing `session_start();`.

Comment: @FirstOne Done.

Comment: It didn't work.Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\doktor\am.php on line 5

Comment: Don't use `$_GET['id'] = $id;` in your code. Copy paste the code I mentioned in the answer.